# how to invoke groovy function with Docker Registry in jenkins shared lib

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecr

i want to push image in ECR

```
stage('login_ecr') {
    steps {
        script {
            withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'ecr:us-east-1:ecr_credentials', url: 'https://***********.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
        }    
    }
}
stage('build-image'){
    steps{
        script{
            build_docker_image (IMAGE_NAME: "${server}", IMAGE_TAG:"${TAG}",AWS_REGION: "us-east-1")
        }
    }
}
```

but i am facing below error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke   at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:282)